# deploy gradle project to tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, deployment, gradle

I have a gradle project, and as I'm working on the project, I would like to deploy to an existing tomcat instance I have. That tomcat server has other things on it that I need to integrate this. It looks like the gradle tomcat plugin deploys to an embedded version, but is there a way to deploy to a standalone tomcat instance?

Answer (score 5):

You could try the [Cargo plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin) which allows you to deploy to a local and remote Tomcat container. The documentation has a full example for Tomcat so you should be able get this set up easily.

Comment: can the tomcat plugin deploy to a non embedded tomcat instance?

Comment: No, it's limited to the embedded container and aligns with the functionality of the core Jetty plugin.